# Dynamic Programming solution for problem "Number of 'B' characters in the first k characters of a fibonacci string"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

so I encountered this coding problem:

> A Fibonacci string of A's and B's is constructed as follows:
>
> F(0) = "A", F(1) = "B" 
> F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) *with n > 1*
>
> Given an integer *n* and *k*, count the occurrence of character 'B' in the first *k* characters of the *n-th* Fibonacci string.
> Constraints: n <= 45, k <= length of F(n).

Currently I'm trying to solve it using Memoization, but the solution results in a RTE and 8/10 correct test cases. I'm hoping to get some correction in my approach and if possible, even better, a more optimized solution for this. Thank you all in advance and here's my current solution using C++:

```
void solve(int n, long long k) {
    vector<string> fib;
    fib.push_back("A"); fib.push_back("B");
    if(n==0) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
    }
    else if (n==1 && k==1) {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    else if (n==1 && k==0) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
    }
    else {
        string toPush = fib[1] + fib[0];

        while(toPush.length() < k) {
            fib.push_back(toPush);
            toPush = fib[fib.size()-1] + fib[fib.size()-2];
        }

        fib.push_back(toPush);

        long long countB = 0;
        string finalStr = fib[fib.size()-1];
        for(long long i = 0; i<k; i++) {
            if(finalStr[i]=='B') countB++;
        }
        cout << countB << endl;
    }
}
```

This approach was based on my observation that the order of the concatenation was **f(n-1) + f(n-2)**, which means **f(2) = 'B' + 'A' = "BA", f(3) = "BA" + 'B' = "BAB"** and so on.

Comment: Manually compute, and then write down, the number of Bs in the first few. This gives 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 ... What do you notice?!!!

Comment: The purpose of `k` is unclear to me from the problem description. Looking at your code, it looks like the maximum number of characters to check - is this correct?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind here but where does the memoization part happen?

Comment: Try ```cout << (int)( std::pow( 1.618033988749894848, n ) / 2.2360679775 + 0.5 );```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes you're right! The problem states that we only need to count occurences of "B" in the first `k` characters of the resulting string

Comment: @Friedrich Oh yeah now I figured memoization and DP are quite different. I'll edit the title. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @lastchance Oh that's a Fibonacci sequence. That's a real nice observation!

Comment: @dvmbCateDoinAStroll excellent. Now I hate to say it but what you're doing is not dynamic programming either. What you're writing is an iterative algorithm and that's a good approach to the problem.

Comment: You're trying to cache all the possible strings, and it's not efficient. Let's say n = 45 and k = length of F(45), so how many bytes did you use? Actually, to build up an F(n) string, you just need F(n-1) and F(n-2) strings, you don't need F(n-3) anymore. Try to reuse the variable

Comment: Another observation is if k <= length of F(n-1) string, then the first k characters of F(n) are the first k characters of F(n-1). Otherwise, the number of 'B' in the first k characters of F(n) is the total of number of 'B' in F(n-1) and number of 'B' in the first (k - len(F(n-1))) characters of F(n-2). The length of F(n) and the number of 'B' in F(n) can be calculated as the same as calculating the Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 1):

- We have `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` so if `F(n-1)` is longer or equal to `k`, the first `k` characters of `F(n)` are also the first `k` characters of `F(n-1)`.
- Otherwise, the first `k` characters of `F(n)` are `F(n-1) + g{k-l}(n-2)` with `g{k-l}(n-2)` and `l` are the first `k-l` characters and the length of `F(n-2)`, respectively.
- So we solve this problem by doing some math without building up the actual string to count the number of 'B'.

  - As the comment of @lastchance, the number of 'B' in the `F(n)` is `n`-index (0-based index) Fibonacci number.
  - You can easily find out that the length of `F(n)` is `(n+1)`-index Fibonacci number.

```
// precompute the fibonacci sequence
void precompute(std::vector<unsigned long long> &fib, int n) {
    fib[0] = 0; fib[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
}

unsigned long long compute(const std::vector<unsigned long long> &fib, int n, long long k) {
    if (k == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 2)
        return fib[n];
    
    // fib[n] is the length of F(n-1)
    // fib[n-1] is the number of 'B' in the F(n-1)
    if (k < fib[n])
        return compute(fib, n-1, k);
    else if (k == fib[n])
        return fib[n-1];
    else
        return fib[n-1] + compute(fib, n-2, k-fib[n-1]);
}

void solve(int n, long long k) {
    std::vector<unsigned long long> fib(n+1);
    precompute(fib, n);

    std::cout << compute(fib, n, k) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kokonut. I'll try this out and see what happens! :>

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct, but you failed to draw the consequences: since you concatenate the two previous strings, the number of B's in the resulting string is the sum of the number of B's in the previous strings - i.e., it's the nth Fibonacci number.

Here is an iterative solution to compute the nth Fibo number in Python (sorry, I'm not good at C++):

```
def fibo(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    prev = 0
    curr = 1
    for _ in range(2, n+1):
        prev, curr = curr, prev+curr
    return curr

fibo(50)
12586269025
```

Comment: Oh man thank you for this interesting observation! However I forgot one important detail in the question description: **I only need to count the occurrences of "B" in the first `k` characters of the *n-th* Fibonacci string**. Using just the Fibonacci value won't work in this case I'm afraid.